# Yum error when updating / install

Tags: linux, yum

**Yum error** are the RHN servers down or is there a problem on my server.

```
 yum update
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Error communicating with server. The message was:

Error Message:
    RHN Proxy could not successfully connect its RHN parent. Please contact your system administrator.
Error Class Code: 1000
Error Class Info: RHN Proxy error.
Explanation:
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please enter a bug report at bugzilla.redhat.com.
     If you choose to submit the bug report, please be sure to include
     details of what you were trying to do when this error occurred and
     details on how to reproduce this problem.

Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Skipping security plugin, no data
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Comment: Check in `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date` and make sure the values are sane for your environment. Pay special attention to 'serverURL' and the Proxy settings.

Comment: @packs, should that not be an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @WesleyDavid: I don't like using answers for debugging questions.

Comment: @Packs You confuzzled me with a lack of a question mark. Ninja!

Answer (score 2):

The error is exactly what it says: it can't connect to the RHN server.  If you paste the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date` (as @packs suggested in his comment), you can use the URL to verify whether or not its up.  For example, if you were using a mirror, that mirror is--perchance--shutdown.

Also verify that your server has internet connectivity, and try running a traceroute to the server (and other URLs) to make sure its not a local problem.